# Getting 500: Precondition Failed when Patching a folder. Why?

Tags: google-drive-api

Intermittently, I'm seeing this error from Drive when I run Patch (Java client library) on a folder to update its status. Retrying doesn't make the problem go away.

I'm guessing that ...

- This should really be a 412 (not a 500)
- Patch is doing an etag comparison, whereas by changing the code to Update, it won't

fwiw I've changed my code to use Update, but since the problem is intermittent, I can't be sure that my resolution is valid. It would be great if somebody with access to some documentation could confirm (or point me in the right direction).

The code is ...

```
driveService.files().patch(enFolder.getId(),enFolder).execute();
```

Comment: See my answer to the same problem [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18381687/1828559

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use update safely if you have the latest state of the file, Drive API should not respond even with a 412 in your case, because you're not setting an `If-Match` header.